# how to recursive query in SPARQL and return the hierarchical relationship

Tags: sparql

I want to implement a recursive query in SPARQL. For example, now there is a **class A**, a **subclass B** is on the side of class A, a subclass C is on the side of B, etc. It is unclear how many subclasses are under the A, and I want to find out below the A all subclasses, and get the relationship between each subclass, for example, know that B is a subclass of A and C is a subclass of B.

Now I can get the relationship between each class by

```
SELECT ?sub_class ?paren_class
WHERE {
    ?sub_class <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing> .
    ?sub_class <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf> ?p
}
```

but how can I know the hierarchical relationship for example : A is the first node, B is the second node, C is the third node. I don't know if I made it clear. In fact I need this hierarchical relationship to set different styles in the visualization process.

Comment: Hi @shaoyi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. To have the best possible chance of getting a good answer to your question, you will need to provide a bit more details of what you're after, what you've tried, and where you're stuck. You can [edit] your question to make it clearer. Have a look at [ask] for tips on how to write a great question!

Comment: In particular: please clarify what you mean with "the first node" and "the second node". It might help if you showed a diagram of the hierarchy you have in mind, or perhaps even a small sample RDF dataset.

Comment: SPARQL has limitations. Knowing the depth isn't really possible once you have cycles in the hierarchy. Getting paths isn't really possible. Just doing `select ?sub ?sup where {?s rdfs:subClassOf :sup}` and doing the rest in the client code is the better way to go.

Comment: The only other way is to do `select ?super ?sub (count(?mid) as ?distance) { 
  ?sub rdfs:subClassOf* ?mid .
  ?mid rdfs:subClassOf+ ?super .
}
group by ?super ?sub 
order by ?super ?sub` - but it will fail with multiple paths between a pair of nodes for sure

Answer (score 0):

You can use property paths

```
SELECT ?x ?y
WHERE {
    ?x rdfs:subClassOf+ ?y
}
```

For more about on property paths, please refer [property paths](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths)

Comment: thank you very much!!!now I can get the result of the all subClass of A ,but I can't know the level of these subClass,I want to the result tell me that A is the first node,B is the second node,C is the third node.